# Extend User Model or Custom Pipeline in Social-App-Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I am implementing [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) (not the deprecated one; the one that relies on Python-social-auth) with django 1.11 (not using Mongo). My application will need to store and manipulate a lot of data on users other than that which is fetched from their social media accounts at login.

I don't need to fetch or collect any extra data when the user authenticates, but various actions they perform on my site will need to be saved to their user model. I am wondering which of the following approaches is preferred (I've searched extensively online, but can't find a specific explanation of why to use one vs the other):

- Create my own user model in my app's models.py (call it `MyUser`) that doesn't extend anything special, and then add a function in the authentication pipeline that associates the social-app-django user with a corresponding instance of `MyUser`. Leave `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` unchanged.

  or...
- Create my own user model in my app's models.py, and in the project's settings.py set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` to point to `MyUser`. Leave the pipeline unchanged. In this case, I was wondering whether someone could clarify what `MyUser` and its manager should extend, and what I need to import in modules.py (I am confused because a lot of stack overflow posts are referring to deprecated versions of this module and I keep getting errors). Also, in this case should I be setting both `AUTH_USER_MODEL` ***and*** `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL`, or just one of them?

Do these two methods essentially achieve the same thing? Is one more reliable/preferred for some reason? Or, should I be doing both? Thanks very much for any assistance.

Another detail: I would like to be able to access the User database not only from the app I am currently building, but also from other apps (within the same Django project) that I will build in the future. Does this affect anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I see this has a decent number of views I will post the solution I eventually came to.

Both `django` and `social-app-django` (or any other social auth module) make use of the default `User` model for authentication. While it's possible to edit this model to add custom parameters, I don't recommend it. It's not good abstraction or modularization. If you make a mistake when configuring the model, you won't just break a specific feature on your site, but you might also break the authentication itself.

**The only circumstances I can think of under which you'd want to edit the default user model itself is if you need to make changes that affect the authentication flow itself (for example, adding your own custom authentication provider).**

It's much easier and safer to create a new model called `UserProfile`, with a required one-to-one relationship to a `User` object. Now, you can treat the `User` object as the authentication part, and the `UserProfile` object as the content/storage part. You won't have to mess with the `User` model very often, and the `UserProfile` model doesn't matter for authentication purposes. Note that in this configuration you should NOT need to change the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` or `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` fields in the settings.py file.

If you take this approach, you will need to add a custom step in the authentication pipeline in which you create a new `UserProfile` object and associate it with the `User` who is currently logging in.

Comment: Don't you see it possible to extend `UserSocialAuth` from the `social_django` module? How can that be done in a compatible way?